# 10 Best (fill in the blank) providers. Close?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I'm on the fence about voting to close [**this question**](https://serverfault.com/questions/67332/10-best-ssl-cert-providers) on SF as subjective and argumentative.  What do you guys do on SO with regards to this?  I'd probably be ok if it wasn't "10 best...", but this is a bit broad.  We don't get these too often on SF.

Comment: Change the title to "Must have SSL cert providers" and then you'll be sweet.

Comment: Oh no , YAMH questions ... ;)

Comment: How about this question too: Top 10 Gotchas... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442473/top-10-gotchas-using-shared-hosting-with-asp-net

Comment: For the record, I just edited the question this time but next time I'm going the "close it" route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Change the title to "Must have SSL cert providers" and then you'll be sweet. – random 8 mins ago
>
> @random: I like that idea. Move that to an answer so I can accept :) – squillman 2 mins ago

Comment: Dammit it smeagol! Why did you make it a wiki? You're losing out on arbitrary numbers!

Comment: Heh, nice try

Comment: Sickening that you, Gollum, don't live up to your name. Would have been far more impressed had you posted this as a normal answer and steeled your cojones for the upvotes.

Comment: I didn't want to get rep thanks to **you**. You filthy little... **what ARE YOU!?**

Comment: For now, we'll go with Shelob.

Comment: If so, now you shall know me as

Comment: Sneaky bugger! You keep changing your name so often it's like you're trying to avoid the path of the Ring Wraiths.

Comment: So this is what I ended up doing.  Props to smeagol for scamming the answer :)

Answer (score 6):

This question should definitely be closed. It is both "Subjective & Argumentative" and "Not a real question".

Questions fitting your format are fit to be the title of a blog post. In fact, the OP is essentially asking for blog posts instead of "answers". They are asking for people to compile lists of positives and negatives relating to (some tech thing) which is basically farming out your own research. In general, these questions about the *single best something* are frowned upon because they are subjective and invite flame wars. In this case it is even more so because they are asking for a body of research to be done.

Furthermore, questions of this sort are not particularly applicable to S[O|F|U] because of the changing nature of the technologies. Acceptable questions are about solvable problems.

> I.E. "My system has these specs: XYZ. I have these symptoms: ABC"

That will remain applicable, because the system doesn't change. It *may* be applicable to other systems, but the solution should remain applicable to that particular problem.

> "What is the best thing to do XYZ"

That question will become stale the moment the next startup rolls out its signature product. New startups appear every few hours. This question won't serve as a repository of valid up-to-date information unless someone is intent on maintaining and updating it. Then again, that runs completely counter to the purpose of the site, it is not meant to host blogs or lists. It is supposed to be strictly Q & A. Subjective stuff only meets 50% of those criteria.

So, after a lengthy, meandering, tangential response:

**Close it.**

Comment: devinb
4,900●2●21 mmm... arbitrary numbers...

Comment: But, to be fair. My arbitrary numbers are the best.

Comment: No one can beat devinb's arbitrariness, except maybe random.

Comment: @Brad Better believe it!

Answer (score 3):

Not a real question. How's he gonna limit the responses to 10 answers? Or is everyone supposed to provide their personal top-10 list, and let readers vote?

And... Who needs 10 SSL providers anyway?

If he just wants a ranked list of SSL providers, he should have made the question CW and pre-populated it with those he's considering, inviting readers to vote for their favorites. That's still bordering on an abuse of the system, but at least it has a slim chance of actually being useful to someone for a short time.

Comment: +1 not a real question is right for polls, supercedes subjectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the question to 'Who are the best providers..."